# Log user login time with php and show it on website

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about saving the moment a person logged in on my website.
Let's say User John logged into my website on 17 January 2018 time: 16:24.

I want to put that date in my footer on my website, but how?

Is there a just a simple way with a PHP function?

Example:

```
John - Logged in sice 17 January 2018 16:24
```

Comment: How do you currently handle sessions ? When the user logs in you could store in a column the `time()` and then in the footer `echo date($storedValue)`

Comment: were you able to store details to db ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when user logs in, set the time in session :

```
$_SESSION['logged_in_datetime'] = date("d M Y H:i");
```

and then, if you want to just display it and do not want to query the db,

```
<?php 
echo $_SESSION['username']."  - Logged in since ".$_SESSION['logged_in_datetime'];
?>
```

Comment: this will display current date and time, which is definitely different than login time

Comment: I would store `time()` and then `date("d M Y H:i",$_SESSION['logged_in_datetime'] )` this way it is much easier to work with if you want to do more stuff with it

Comment: Although, it has many other drawback, but it answers the OP question. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple sql query. You should have a datetime type field in your database table and you can query the user and show the last logged time value.